# Как понимать dns-секцию дополнительной информации?

Tags: dns

В общем, купил доменное имя у регистратора Д.И. и в настройках ответственного dns-сервера указал свой ip-адрес, далее открыл сокет (53-порт) для прослушивания дейтаграмм. Через браузер firefox ввел купленное доменное имя, получил dns-сообщение и принялся его разбирать.

Изучив *[rfc-1035](https://docs.yandex.ru/docs/view?tm=1665055513&tld=ru&lang=ru&name=4rfc1035.pdf&text=rfc%201035%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcreewick.github.io%2Fstudy%2Fcourses%2Finet%2Flectures%2F4rfc1035.pdf&lr=50&mime=pdf&l10n=ru&sign=328139c67eb9fb4a612ddd2ad9ef6cc3&keyno=0&nosw=1&serpParams=tm%3D1665055513%26tld%3Dru%26lang%3Dru%26name%3D4rfc1035.pdf%26text%3Drfc%2B1035%2B%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%2B%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BC%26url%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2Fcreewick.github.io%2Fstudy%2Fcourses%2Finet%2Flectures%2F4rfc1035.pdf%26lr%3D50%26mime%3Dpdf%26l10n%3Dru%26sign%3D328139c67eb9fb4a612ddd2ad9ef6cc3%26keyno%3D0%26nosw%3D1)* и опираясь на эти знания разобрал заголовок, вопросительный раздел, ответ, но с разделом доп. информации я просто стою на месте уже пару дней, не могу понять его структуру, хотя в рфц указано что раздел ответа,полномочий и дополнительный имеют одинаковую структуру т.е. в начале записи доменное имя(метки или указатель) и т.д..

На изображении в первой строке символьное представление днс-запроса во второй строке оно интерпретировано в числа, все символы и числа разделены штрихом шеффера для удобства чтения. Заголовка dns нет в изображении но имеется в виду что это запрос, 1-запись в вопросительном разделе (типа А) и 1-запись в разделе доп. информации. По другому изображение начинается с первой метки доменного имени.

После красной черты начинается не понятная мне сигнатура, но это первый байт после вопросительного раздела. Сообщение отображено как есть т.е. с прямым порядком байт и числа типа "unsigned char":

[image: Скриншот терминала]

Помогите пж.

Comment: Пожалуйста, избегайте вставлять текст скриншотом. Это очень неудобно для тех, кто пытается вам помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуем разобраться

Согласно rfc-1035 RR записи начинаются с доменного имени, за которым следуют два октета, кодирующие тип записи (TYPE).

В вашем случае доменное имя это `0` - корень. А TYPE - `0 41`.
В [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) узнаем, что тип 41 это *`OPT` pseudo-record type needed to support EDNS*, псевдо-запись для поддержки расширений DNS, регламентированных rfc6891.

Идем в rfc6891 и смотрим на структуру записи OPT:

```
   +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
   | Field Name | Field Type   | Description                  |
   +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
   | NAME       | domain name  | MUST be 0 (root domain)      |
   | TYPE       | u_int16_t    | OPT (41)                     |
   | CLASS      | u_int16_t    | requestor's UDP payload size |
   | TTL        | u_int32_t    | extended RCODE and flags     |
   | RDLEN      | u_int16_t    | length of all RDATA          |
   | RDATA      | octet stream | {attribute,value} pairs      |
   +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

Итак, NAME у нас `0`, TYPE - `0 41`.
Далее следует 2 октета размера UDP пакета - `5 200`, то есть 5 << 8 + 200 = 1480.

Потом четыре октета RCODE и флагов. Их структура описана отдельно:

```
              +0 (MSB)                            +1 (LSB)
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
0: |         EXTENDED-RCODE        |            VERSION            |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2: | DO|                           Z                               |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Из вашего примера выходит, что:

- EXTENDED-RCODE `0`
- VERSION `0`
- DO `1`
- флаги Z `0`

И завершает все размер RDLEN `0`, то есть дополнительных опций нет.

---

Если говорить о смысле всего этого, то отправитель передает флаг DO, чтобы заявить, что готов получать в ответе RR записи DNSSEC.